# Not allowing encrypted password

Tags: java, xml, encryption

I am using `Smartpool` library for oracle database connection pooling. I can only see the option to provide database information in xml config file in plain text including password. Which is not a good practice. I want password to be stored in encrypted format instead plain text. I can't find way to store encrypted password using Smartpool library. Can someone help me to handle this situation or suggest for alternate solution?

Comment: No you don’t. You want to *securely hash* the password.

Comment: @user207421 Not if you want to be able to obtain the password, which you will need to create the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a lot, I fixed in following ways:

When I looked into history, it's development was discontinued. There was no other way to fix and it's source code was also not available.
I had to do some reverse engineering with Java De-compiler. Created my own class and inherited the existing, added the needed functionality to support encryption and compiled using the same JDK version. This solution worked for me.

So, the final answer of this question is, any change in smartpool lib you have to do your own because there is no active development for this library. Thanks.